# Sequelize best practice for GROUP BY & CROSS JOIN with Variables

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I try to create this query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a746d/1
into Sequelize format.

```
SELECT location, parameter, datetime, value
FROM (
   SELECT location, parameter, datetime, value,
          @seq := IF(@loc = location, @seq + 1,
                     IF(@loc := location, 1, 1)) AS seq
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @loc = '') AS vars
   ORDER By location, datetime desc, value desc) AS t
WHERE t.seq = 1
```

I tried to do the following:

```
getLastPerCategory = function(callback) {
Model.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('location')), 'location'],
    [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('parameter')), 'parameter'],
    [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('datetime')), 'datetime'],
    [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('value')), 'value'],
  ],
  group: ['location'],
  raw: true,
}).then(results => callback(results));
};
```

But it is giving incorrect values.
My goal is to get the last object grouped by 'location'.

location(1,2,3,4).

Thanks in advance,
Svante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its the optimal way but I solved this issue by query it raw instead of doing it in Sequelize format.

```
const query = 'THE QUERY'
sequelize.query(query, 
  { 
    model: Model, mapToModel: true,
    nest: true,
    raw: true,
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT 
  }).then(results => callback(results));
```